# JetBrains IDE custom refactor extract to new file

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, refactoring, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

In JetBrains IDEs there's an option called refactoring witch allow you to easily refactor your code. One of the things it can do is extract some part of your code inside a new file.

For example, when I'm using Angular and I want to make a new component I can select the part of my code that needs to be in the component and tell WebStorm to extract it in a new component which WebStorm will do, it will also add the required code for it to work.

```html
<div class="toto">
    <span class="tata">
        tutu
    </span>
</div>
```

->

```html
<div class="toto">
    <app-titi></app-titi>
</div>
```

+

```html
<span class="tata">
    tutu
</span>
```

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-titi',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [],
    templateUrl: './titi.component.html',
    styleUrl: './titi.component.css'
})
export class TitiComponent {

}
```

The thing is when I'm coding in PHP there's no option to easily extract the code I've selected in a new file so I always have to cut it, create the file, paste my code and then call the new file from the position I cut it which doesn't take to much time but is annoying.

```html
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="get">
        <label>
            <strong>Toto </strong>
            <input name="toto" type="text">
        </label>
    </form>
</body>
```

->

```php
<body>
    <?php require "toto.php"; ?>
</body>
```

+

```html
<form action="index.php" method="get">
    <label>
        <strong>Toto </strong>
        <input name="toto" type="text">
    </label>
</form>
```

I would like to create my own extract template using JetBrains debugging feature but I don't know how to or where to do it.

I've tried looking on Google, StackOverflow, search in my IDE and looked on the JetBrains' docs but I didn't found anything.

Comment: 1) *"I would like to create my own extract template using JetBrains debugging feature"* It needs to be coded as a plugin AFAIK

Comment: 2) *"The thing is when I'm coding in PHP there's no option to easily extract the code I've selected in a new file"* Which code? Provide specific examples, please. Because it CAN refactor the PHP code (introduce constant, field, own method etc)